# Node group input not colored

Tags: node-editor

When I add an Input to the Node Editor Group interface how does it know what type of function it is? The Plug icons are all gray not blue, yellow, green. [image] Screen shot of blender node editor group interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create input sockets by creating a link to the date you want to connect.

The new input socket will have the color of the data is is connected to.

[image]